# DOMDocument saveHTML() returns empty string

Tags: php, domdocument

I am trying to use the PHP DOMDocument class to modify the content of the content of my pages, but it's not going very well.

```
<?php
$d = new DOMDocument();
$c = get_the_content();
$d->loadXML($c);
echo $d->saveHTML();
?>
```

If I echo `$c`, the page is printed as normal, but as above, it doesn't print anything at all. What am I missing here?

Comment: What's the content you're getting?

Comment: Please tell me that in your real code you are using sane variable names? :)

Comment: So does the call to `loadXML()` succeed?   What does `var_dump($d)` tell you? Basic debugging is in order here.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski doing a var_dump returned pretty much empty objects, so it doesn't seem like the loadXML works :/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `loadHTML()` instead of `loadXML()`. With options, to prevent unwanted tags.

```
<?php
$d = new DOMDocument();
$c = get_the_content();
$d->loadHTML($c, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
echo $d->saveHTML();
?>
```

An important difference from `the_content()` is that `get_the_content()` does not pass the content through the 'the_content'. This means that `get_the_content()` will not auto-embed videos or expand shortcodes, among other things.

Also it will not *autop*. But you can apply filters easy:

```
$c = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
```

Care the options for `loadHTML()` are only available with Libxml >= 2.7.7 (as of PHP >= 5.4.0).

Comment: I'm actually working with this, but if it doesn't fit your needs (server), you should try to load and save the same, HTML or XML.